# Win/Tie Check for Tic Tac Toe in Java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to get my code to check for wins and ties for my Tic Tac Toe game. So far, win checks only work for diagonals, but it's still buggy. Tie check doesn't work at all. I need help on my winCheck method and getting it to check for wins across, vertical, and diagonal. I also need help on getting it to print the Player who won the game. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TicTacToe {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter board size (e.g. 5): ");
    int size = 0;
    if(console.hasNextInt()){   //If the console has an integer, sets the size
        size = console.nextInt();
    } else {
        while(!console.hasNextInt()){   //If no integer
            console.next(); //Discards bad input
            System.out.print("Invalid input. Enter a whole positive integer: ");
        }
        size = console.nextInt();   //Sets integer once valid input is entered
    }

    int[][] array = new int[size][size];    //Sets the board size by the input (input x input)
    int i=0;    //Initializing "i" for the loops

    do{
        i=1;    //Resets "i" to one
        for(; i<=2; i++){   //For loop repeating for both players 1 and 2
            System.out.print("Player " + i + "'s Move (row,column): ");
            String plyrInput = console.next();
            //errorCheck(plyrInput, console);
            inputParse(plyrInput, i, array);    //Sends player's coordinates, player number, and the array
            if(winCheck(array, i)==true){
                System.out.print("Game over.");
                break;
            }
        }

    }while(winCheck(array, i)==false);
    console.close();
}

public static String errorCheck(String input, Scanner console){
    while(!input.contains(",")){
        console.next();
        System.out.print("Please re-enter in proper format; row,column: ");
    }
    return console.next();
}



public static void inputParse(String input, int player, int[][] array){
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(input, ",");   //Parses input by comma

    String row = tokens.nextToken();    //First part of input
    String column = tokens.nextToken(); //Second part of input

    int rowNum = Integer.parseInt(row)-1;   //Decreases the inputs by one for the array
    int colNum = Integer.parseInt(column)-1;

    //System.out.println(rowNum);
    //System.out.println(colNum);

    if(player==1){  //If the player is player one, INCREASES the array location by 1
        ++array[rowNum][colNum];
    } else {        //If the player is player two, DECREASES the array location by 1
        --array[rowNum][colNum];
    }


    for(int x=0; x<array[0].length; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<array.length; y++){
            System.out.print(array[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    boardPrint(array);
}

public static void boardPrint(int[][] array){
    System.out.print("+");
    for(int size=0; size<array.length; size++){ //Prints the "+-+-+-+" part of board according to given size
        System.out.print("-+");
    }
    System.out.println();

    for(int row=0; row<array[0].length; row++){
        for(int column=0; column<array.length; column++){
            System.out.print("|");
            if(array[row][column]==1){  //If the array index has 1, prints out "X" (for player 1)
                System.out.print("X");
            } else if(array[row][column]==-1){  //If negative 1, prints out "O" (for player 2)
                System.out.print("O");
            } else {    
                System.out.print(" ");  //Otherwise if array something else, prints out a regular space
            }
        }
        System.out.println("|");

        System.out.print("+");
        for(int size=0; size<array.length; size++){
            System.out.print("-+");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static boolean winCheck(int[][] array, int player){
    int counter = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++){
        if(array[i][i] == array[i+1][i+1]){
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter==array.length){
            System.out.println("Player " + player + " wins.");
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Your diagonal check checks `array[0][0]==array[1][1]` and `array[1][1]=array[2][2]`.  Great.  What comparisons would you have to make to check a row?  What about a column?  What about the other diagonal?  Write out those comparisons, and you will probably spot some patterns that you can use to figure out what to code.

Comment: That's the part I'm kind of stuck on. I know i could just repeat the code for the other diagonal, but I'm trying to find a simpler way to do it. That's what I need help on.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an exercise, so I'm only going to give an outline of an answer.  But if you want to simplify the checking logic, I'd write a method that looks sort of like

```
static boolean checkLine(int[][] array, int startRow, int startCol, int rowIncrement, int colIncrement) { 
    ...
}
```

This would return `true` if everything in one straight line of the array is equal (and not an empty square), and `false` otherwise.  For the diagonal you already coded, you'd call

```
win = checkLine(array, 0, 0, 1, 1);
```

because you're going to start looking at `array[0][0]`, and each square you check will be at the row 1 more than the previous row, and the column 1 more than the previous column (thus `array[1][1]`, `array[2][2]`).

To check the bottom row, where you'd be looking at `array[2][0]`, `array[2][1]`, `array[2][2]`, you'd call it like this:

```
win = checkLine(array, 2, 0, 0, 1);
```

which means you start at row 2 and column 0, and then to check the other squares, you add 0 to the row number (since you're staying in the same row) and 1 to the column number.

You can work out how to do this for each row, column, and diagonal.  You'd call `checkLine` 8 times (3 rows, 3 columns, 2 diagonals).